# how to extract the maximum and minimum values of a csv file using python

Tags: python, list, csv, readline

i have a python script that read from csv file that includes 3 columns

- date
- minTemprature
- maxTemperature

and i need to extract

1. min value existing in minTemprature column
2. max value existing in maxTemperature column

where is the error in my script ?

## code:

```
import csv
mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")
myfile.readline()
myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
mywind,mydate=[],[]
minTemp, maxTemp = [],[]
for row in myreader:
    print(row[1],row[2])
    minTemp.append(row[1])
    maxTemp.append(row[2])

theindex=minTemp.index(min(minTemp))
print("the min value is : ", minTemp[theindex])
```

Comment: Can you post tour csv data?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "where is the error in my script ?" => how could we know ? You don't say anything about any "error".

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the min and max you can do something like this:

**EDIT**: Changed the code based on comments

```
import csv

with open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv") as myfile:
    myreader=csv.reader(myfile,delimiter=';')
    content = list(myreader)
    minTemp = min([int(elem[1]) for elem in content])
    maxTemp = max([int(elem[2]) for elem in content])

print("the min value is : ", minTemp)
print("the max value is : ", maxTemp)
```

Comment: This will not work - the first list expression (which should actually be a generator expression - no need to build a list here) will consume all the file, so the second one will always yield an empty list. You'd have to reset the file pointer  between the two statements, butand parsing the whole file twice is very inefficient anyway. Also, feeding strings to `min` and   `max` may not yield the expected result (try `min(str(x) for x in range(5, 15))` to find out why).

Comment: `myreader = ...; content = list(myreader); minTemp = min(elem[0] for elem in content); maxTemp = max(elem[2] for elem in content)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy for that

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv", delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2)

min_min_T = np.min(data[:, 0])
max_max_T = np.max(data[:, 1])
```